# commons-io FileFilter to filter multiple files

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I have to get a list of all of the files from a folder with a particular extension, excluding all from a particular list.

I've looked at "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles()", and the variation that takes the "fileFilter" parameter, which is of type IOFileFilter.  I've also looked at all the implementations of IOFileFilter, like "NameFileFilter", which takes a single file name.

What I don't see is an obvious convention for excluding all of a list of files.  The Regex variation won't work.

Comment: Create a file filter with a Set of names which you check.

Comment: Ok, should have realized that.  I actually found a different way to do this, as I'm using Groovy, so I just call "eachFileRecurse()" on my directory name and assert each candidate.

Comment: I would create `List<File>` as you mentioned above and then filter it out using `Iterables.filter(list, new Predicate<File>() {...} )`